# Database replication, certain tables not updating

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two databases set up, both of which are part of a NDB cluster. The replication works successfully for most tables, however upon updating a few specific tables, they don't update on the clustered nodes, therefore I have to manually go change them. Where could I look to see the settings for which tables should be updated and which shouldn't.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: You should probably avoid NDB....

Comment: You would have set those parameters in your my.cnf yourself...I am assuming since your asking you did not...from my experience, usually if replication is not working right, it has to do with improper set up to begin with...How did you initially set up your replication environment?